# Texas Hold em question

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, poker

First player has Ace Seven.

Second player has Ace Seven.

Third Player has pocket Jacks.

Community cards are A J 5 5 5.

What is the winning hand in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the best 5-card hand that each player can create from 5 cards.  (Since you didn't specify the suits, this assumes that nobody can create a flush.)

Players 1 and 2 have `A 7 A J 5 5 5`.  The best hand from these cards is a full house: `5 5 5 A A`.

Player 3 has `J J A J 5 5 5`.  The best hand from these cards is also a full house: `J J J 5 5`.

Since the third player's 3-set (jacks) is higher than the other players' 3-set (fives), player 3 wins the pot.

Comment: Please do not use codeblock for anything that is not actual code.